# Is there any clarification from togashi with his new worktime since 2016?

Tags: hunter-x-hunter, manga-production

Based on [this website](https://hiatus-hiatus.github.io) there is a continously chapter per years for about 10 chapter for every year that mean 1 tankoubon per years. Since when he decide to work only 10 chapter per years ? Is there any clarification from Togashi or Shueisha ?

[image: HunterxHunter Hiatus Chart]

Answer (score 2):

The autor is suffering from prolonged [back pains](https://www.animenewsnetwork.com/news/2014-09-04/hunter-hunter-manga-hiatus-continues-until-further-notice/.78384) and hasn't been able to recover.

While the exact reason [isn't always stated](https://www.animenewsnetwork.com/news/2006-02-12/hunter-x-hunter-interupted), Togashi's chronic illness is a well known issue and mostly assumed to be the reason for pretty much all the hiatuses.